Cannot find the dynamic library in Xcode
Sorry, this question is not about programming.
I have a problem in the Xcode 15.0 where the custom Dynamic library cannot be found during build. The dynamic library is built for iOS 16 and I have added it to Link Binary with Libraries and also to Embed Libraries as Destination: Framework. In the General->Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content I can see the library is loaded and Embed&Sign option is set. In Build Settings the Library search path is also set to the location of library $(PROJECT_DIR)/test/lib
Library is available in this location: $(PROJECT_DIR)/test/lib
I can build the project without any issues. But when I try to run the application, I get below error:
dyld[1076]: Library not loaded: libtest-xx.dylib
Referenced from: <4A9...>
Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libtest-xx.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache
//libtest-xx.dylib' (no such file)

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here and how to correctly bundle dynamic library with the application?
Do I need to install this library anywhere before running the application?
Thanks in advance
P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing

When you finish building the external library, you will need to modify its install name (using install_name_tool -id ...) to @rpath/libtest-xx.dylib.  The app executable should have the frameworks folder in its runpath, so will know where to load the library from.

Hi @trojanfoe, thanks for the response. Can you please let me know what is id in install_name_tool ? And do I need to run this command in xcode?

It sets the path of the library so that code that links to it knows where to load it from.  Try otool -L on the library to show the current value. You should do it at the end of whatever process is used to build the library; if that's in Xcode then there is an install name setting you can change.

Hi @trojanfoe, okay. I am new to ios programming so I have a question about this. The library libtest-xx.dylib is built separately. And this library is being used in a SeiftUI application. I have set the Link binary with Libraries and Embed Library option in Xcode to this library. So loading library within the application should be taken care by Xcode right? Maybe my understanding is wrong here

No that sounds right.

But still I get above error when I try to build and run the application on ipad. In the Xcode I select ipad as the target while building. I also tried to run the application by copying it to ipad but it doesn't work. How can I make sure that application has bundled the library and also the paths are correct?

Yes you can examine the built app in the DerivedData directory. Make sure the library is in the right place and check the main executable is referencing it via @rpath and not the path where it was built. Did you change the install name as I suggested?

@trojanfoe, changing install name worked. Thanks for the hint

Hi @trojanfoe, I have a question, not related to above issue. I am writing a small application that can detect USB smartcards (CCID compliant) devices on ipad/iphone. I am using CryptoTokenKit framework for this. Is it the correct framework to use for this? or is it only for macOS?
